# Generate 100 values with Weibull distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution, random, weibull

I am new to R and I am having problems using the Weibull distribution function.

I have to use cumulative distribution, so I have to use pweibull function. I also know that the shape must be between 0.7 and 0.8.

```
 pweibull(q, shape, scale = 1, lower.tail = T, log.p = F)
```

Now here comes the tricky part, for the q parameter, I am required to pass random values calculated via the Weibull inverse, this inverse will have random values between 0 and 1 as input. Does this function work?

```
pdiweibull(x, q, beta)
```

Summarizing, if I create a vector of 100 random numbers with values from 0 to 1, pass it to pdiweibull as "x" parameter, and then pass that result to pweibull as "q" parameter, am I translating my thoughts correctly to R code?

Comment: What is `pdiweibull`? I don't think it is a function in `base` R.

Comment: I found the pdiweibull here, http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DiscreteInverseWeibull/docs/rdiweibull

Comment: The inverse is `qweibull`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in the Weibull distribution, you should not be using the "discrete inverse Weibull distribution", which is something rather different.

Instead just use the four [Weibull distribution functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Weibull.html)

```
dweibull(x, shape, scale = 1, log = FALSE)
pweibull(q, shape, scale = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
qweibull(p, shape, scale = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
rweibull(n, shape, scale = 1)
```

for the density, distribution function, quantile function and random values.

`rweibull(100, shape=0.75, scale=1)` will give a hundred values, perhaps of the form you want, as would `qweibull(runif(100), shape=0.75, scale=1)` or possibly something like `qweibull(x, shape=0.75, scale=1)` where `x` is a vector of 100 random values between 0 and 1